# Need help to construct an environment

Tags: environments

I am typesetting a document, and I am trying to convert a command into a environment. Here is the original code and the first environment (which actually works).

```
\newcommand{\crub}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\small #1}}%
\end{center}
}

\newenvironment{crub}{   % new environment instead of command
\begin{trivlist}
\centering
\bfseries
\color{red}
\item\relax
}{\end{trivlist}}
```

Now, here is the code for the command that I cannot seem to get into a proper environment.

```
\newcommand{\psalmheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\noindent\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\large #1}}%
\end{center}
}
```

To explain further, here is a part of the original doc, BEFORE I tried to change commands into environments:

```
%Beginning of the Preamble % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

%Document Class and Packages to use % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.05cm,right=2.10cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,color,fancyhdr,framed,titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

%Shortcut Commands % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand\stich[1]{%
\textcolor{red}{S.  }#1%
}

\newcommand\response[1]{%
\textcolor{red}{R.  }#1%
}

\newcommand{\psalmheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\noindent\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\large #1}}%
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\noindent\textcolor{black}{\textbf{\large #1}}%
\end{center}
}


\newcommand{\hourheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\noindent\textcolor{black}{\textbf{\large #1}}%
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\lessonheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\noindent\normalsize\textcolor{red}{#1}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\rub}[1]{%
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\small #1}}%
}

\newcommand{\brub}[1]{%
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{\small #1}}%
}

\newcommand{\crub}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\small #1}}%
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\cbrub}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\small #1}}%
}


%Formatting to Center the Chapter, Section, and Subsection Titles % 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1.0ex minus 0.2ex}{2.3ex plus 0.2ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\centering}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1.0ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}
%End of the Preamble % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

%Title Info % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\title{AN ORTHODOX RULE OF PRAYER.}
\author{Father Thomas Moore, Michael Dykes}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents



\part{SUNDAY PRAYERS.}
\chapter{SATURDAY EVENING PRAYERS.}
\crub{Towards evening, we stand before the holy icons (having lit a candle     and maybe some incense), with reverence and fear of God; we gather our thoughts, make the Sign of the Cross, and say:}

In the Name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit. Amen.

\begin{framed}
\crub{From St. Thomas Sunday until Ascension, instead of \textbf{O God,  cleanse me, a sinner \ldots we say:}}
\textrm{Christ is risen from the dead, trampling down death by death, and  upon those in the tombs bestowing life. \crub{(thrice)}}

\crub{During any Vigil-rank Festal Period [(see Appendix A) - including your and your Temple's Patronal Feast Day], we begin our prayers by praying the Festal Troparia (again, see Appendix A).}

\crub{Then, in either case, we immediately pray the Trisagion Prayers as below:}
\end{framed}

\crub{Afterwards, we collect our thoughts, and make seven prostrations (or metanoias), saying:}

\section{THE SEVEN--BOW BEGINNING.}
O God, be merciful to me, a sinner. 

O God, cleanse me, a sinner, and have mercy on me.

Thou hast created me, O Lord, have mercy on me. 

Countless times have I sinned, O Lord, forgive me. 

All-holy Lady Theotokos, save me, a sinner, 

O Angel, my holy Guardian, protect me from all evil. 

O Saint, \crub{N}, my Patron pray to God for me. 

\crub{Then, we begin the Evening Prayers with these words:}

\section{THE INTRODUCTORY PRAYERS.}
O Lord Jesus Christ our God, through the prayers of our Thine All-pure Mother, of our holy and God-bearing Fathers, and of all the saints, have mercy on us. Amen.

Glory to Thee, O our God, Glory to Thee.

O Heavenly King, the Comforter, the Spirit of Truth, Who art everywhere present and fillest all things, Treasury of blessings and Giver of Life: Come and abide in us; and cleanse us from every impurity, and save our souls, O Good One.

\section{TRISAGION PRAYERS.}
Holy God. Holy Mighty. Holy Immortal. Have mercy on us. \crub{(thrice)}

\end{document}
```

Upon compiling, I see the section and chapter headings, then to the left of thes, I see a 'shadowed' section and chapter heading. That is what I was trying to get rid of. Thanks again, because at this point, I am a bit lost.

Comment: What's the point? The two commands do exactly the same (apart from `\large` instead of `\small`).

Comment: The first obviously cannot work, because the `crub` environment does not contain `\small`, whereas the command `\crub` contains it. And another thing: **Never use the same name on both a command and an environment, because it creates a macro name clash.**

Comment: I may not be fully understanding you (or maybe I was not really clear when asking my question), but I do not have both the crub command and the crub environment in the same doc. Due to other issues (which are solved by using the environment), I am using that instead of the the command. I am foregoing the /small there. Additionally, I wish to convert the /psalmheading to environment form, if possible. Thanks. Oh, sorry the second block of code was what I was trying to do to convert the \psalmheading to an environment form.

Comment: Just to give you an idea of what is going on, here is part of my doc (the original):

Answer (score 1):

There are unnecessary bits in your definition of the `crub` environment:

```
\newenvironment{crub}
  {\begin{center}\color{red}\bfseries\small}
  {\end{center}}
```

is simpler. Actually `center` is defined with `trivlist`, but it's better to stick with higher level objects as long as it is possible.

The same strategy works with `psalmheading`:

```
\newenvironment{psalmheading}
  {\begin{center}\color{red}\bfseries\large}
  {\end{center}}
```

You probably had a problem caused by `\noindent` which starts LR mode so that you got a spurious space in the output; but in `center` the indent is zero anyway.

Comment: One more major question (if I may). Currently, the header is set to the chapter (left header) and the section (right header) which I would like to keep, but in some cases they are overlapping. I need a way for both of them to be lowercase and not ALL CAPS, but am not sure how to do this???

Comment: Try to put `\let\MakeUppercase\relax` in your preamble. This will prevent LaTeX from uppercasing the marks (instead of "making uppercase", the LateX will just "relax for a while".

Comment: @MichaelDykes Look at the packages `fancyhdr` or `titleps` for a way to customize your headers.

Comment: @tohecz When I tried adding   \let\MakeUppercase\relax   to my preamble, I ended up with several blank sheets at the beginning of the doc???

Comment: @MichaelDykes It's not a good idea to redefine an important command of LaTeX. The approach with `fancyhdr` is recommended. The manual is quite clear.

Comment: @egreg So should I use the following commands from fancyhdr to eliminate the uppercase:     \lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}            When I try this, I end up with an error mssg:"Emergency stop."

Comment: Also now, I am (in addition to the above error) getting the following error: "Package xcolor error: UNDEFINED color RED."

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is a solution (it defines the environment `psalmheading`, just using the TeX primitives, I prefer it this way):

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\psalmheading{\center\large\bfseries\color{red}}
\def\endpsalmheading{\endcenter}
```

Using the more standard LaTeX commands should be the same:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{psalmheading}{% percent-sign and the end of line to remove spaces
  \center\large\bfseries\color{red}%
}{\endcenter}
```

`\endcenter` is the ending command of `\center`. You are used to put `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, but `\center...\endcenter` runs a bit faster (and there're few more technical differences).

And you can use any formatting commands in the place of `\large\bfseries\color{red}`.

**Full test code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\psalmheading{\center\begingroup\noindent\large\bfseries\color{red}}
\def\endpsalmheading{\endgroup\endcenter}

\usepackage{lipsum} % package to add some dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % inputs some random text

\begin{psalmheading}
\lipsum[2] % inputs some random text
\end{psalmheading}

\lipsum[3] % inputs some random text

\end{document}
```

Edit: the `rub` environment, the most tricky is removal of the next empty line, if there is any:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% got from http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-gobblepars-to-prevent-latex-from.html
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\def\aftergobblepars{\expandafter\gobblepars}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{rub}{%
  \small\bfseries\color{red}%
}{%
  \quad % put any space command here
  \aftergroup\aftergobblepars\gobblepars%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{rub}
LABEL
\end{rub}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @tohecx So, what does the command /lipsum do exactly? Also, could this format be applied to all my other /newcommands (see above)? Thanks again. I am really loving LaTeX and TeX, the more I learn about it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. I added comments to my response.

Comment: @MichaelDykes: `\lipsum` just generates text, so you don't have to type some random text yourself.

Comment: Why `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`? They are added automatically by `\begin` and `\end`. Moreover `\noindent` serves no purpose. Moreover it's preferable to stick with "standard" LaTeX commands, instead of `\def`, whenever possible: a beginner might be confused with the syntax.

Comment: @egreg: `\noindent` shall be omitted, you are right, edited. The grouping is a matter of habits, I often use such commands in the short syntax (`\env...\endenv`) hence the grouping... so again you are right.

Comment: @tohecz Using te above coding for psalmheading works fine, but when I tried to apply this to                                 \rub (the same as \crub but not centered, and no line skip afterwards), I ended up with a line skip afterwards, where I intended it to be inline. Here is what I wrote: \newenvironment{rub}{% 
 \small\bfseries\color{red}%
}
If you can help me with this, I think I have everything else solved. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @MichaelDykes I'm not sure what you want. You want the text to continue 1) on the same line as `rub` contents, 2) on the next line with no vertical space and no indent, or 3) yet something different?

Comment: @tohecz I would like 1) for the text after     rub    to continue on the same line as        rub

Comment: @MichaelDykes: see the answer, I edited it and added the solution.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I am still getting: "undefined color Red"

Comment: Are you sure you have `\usepackage{xcolor}` in the preamble? And if so, try `\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}` instead.

Comment: @tohecx: Sorry I have taken so long to get back to you, but the way you fixed my '\rub' works. And now I no longer have the "Undefined color: RED" any more. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Please disregard my comment stating that I still was getting "undefined color Red". One last thing, is there any way you could explain what the code you supplied for \rub does (I mean I know what it looks like, but it seems complicated to just fix a spacing issue)? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: The spacing issue is complicated, because when you put a **blank line after `\end{rub}`**, then TeX converts this blank line to a start of a new paragraph. The command `\aftergroup` expands its argument after the `\end{rub}` is processed by LaTeX. The command `\gobblepar` removes `\par`=`<emptyline>`. The command `\aftergobblepar` does the same way just with a twist that it can do that even when there are some control commands between `\aftergobblepar` and `\par`. I would say that this is one of the "dirty tricks" in TeX.